# What to do if I think I am mobbed, but I am not sure?

Tags: discussion, support

Which I am doing normally: I maintain the normal & cooperative communication even if it is painful. But it requires a psichological force which I can't/won't maintain on the longterm.

My question were, if better solutions are existing here?

(Mobbing is: collective trolling, bullying, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobbing)

Comment: Uhh...? Wrong site? If this is related to MSO, could you elaborate/reword your questions?

Comment: I think I'm starting to get your question. Sometimes I also have this period. My suggestion is to take a break from this, short or long. Sometimes it's quite difficult to cooperate in community-driven site (in a sense that somebody might disagree with you, etc).

Comment: are you feeling overwhelmed? take a short break, and return feeling refreshed.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "mobbed"?

Comment: @PeterHorvath if you feel it's serious enough to bring up (and if it affects your happiness on the site) compile it into a clear email to the team. I don't know your exact situations, but bullying or harassing, even if done subtly, should not be ignored. So don't hesitate to inform others of it. Even if no direct action is taken, the team will be aware of something that might be going on.

Comment: The advice still stands.

Answer (score 5):

If you're actually being harassed, mobbed or have users act inappropriately towards you, flag for moderator attention. That shouldn't happen and they have the means to either take care of it, or to escalate it to those who can. (Though you could of course also contact the team yourself, if there is a need to do so. Particularly if the "case" doesn't fit in a custom flag).

Other than that, your experience on any of the sites should be a positive one. If it's not, for whatever reason, take a break. Go do something else. Your time is no doubt valuable, and spending it on something that upsets you is not worth it. It somewhat sounds like a burn-out. And if that is the case, forcing yourself to keep participating is not wise. Take a break. Once you feel refreshed and relaxed, then return.

Now, I don't know if this applies to you, but I know of several users who went to similar ups and downs on the site, bringing out the worst in them at some point, who decided to quit. While its a great loss to no longer have their knowledge on the site, sometimes that's for the best. I would not recommend you to leave. But if this is not a one time event, but happens each and every time, it's an option. There's a whole world out there that's not SO/SE.

Of course that last option is rather extreme, and not my first choice. Just take a break. If there is anything the mods or team need to handle, inform them of it. And once that is over, and you feel you like to participate again, please do come back.